# WPF Custom Property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added a new property to the ProgresBar control, how ever I don't think i'm doing it correctly. Below is the progressbar in the MainWindow.xaml, I need to have 2 values with a gap between them.

```
<ProgressBar Style="{StaticResource CircularProgress}" 
                Value="50"
                Extensions:CustomExtensions.Radius="140 0" />
```

Now here is my Custom Extension, I made it a string as there is a gap between the two numbers.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Radius", typeof(string), typeof(CustomExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public static void SetRadius(UIElement element, string value)
{
    element.SetValue(RadiusProperty, value);
}

public static string GetRadius(UIElement element)
{
    return (string)element.GetValue(RadiusProperty);
}
```

Now here is where I use this custom property, which isn't working.

```
<PathFigure x:Name="pathFigure" StartPoint="{Binding Path=Radius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```

Really I have got 2 questions:
1. The values don't seem to be applying to my ControlTemplate, as if I remove the binding an enter `140 0` myself it shows the ArcSegment, however with the binding it doesn't.

2. Is it possible to only type `Radius` for the custom property without `Extensions:CustomExtensions`?

**Edit:**
When attempting to bind a textbox to this value I get this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '36' and line position '20'.

code:

```
<ProgressBar Style="{StaticResource CircularProgress}" 
                     Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource runtimeVariables},Path=uploadProgress}" 
                     Extensions:CustomExtensions.Radius="80" 
                     Name="test"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=test, Path=(Extensions:CustomExtensions.Radius)}"/>
```

Comment: For me binding with element and only "Radius" as path was working (as I posted in my answer after changing the attached property) so if the error is not coming from this, I imagine it might be coming from the previous binding (try without it -> giving hard coded value like in your first example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use special syntax if binding to attached property (with parentheses around the attached property). Also, you should specify a converter to convert string to a Point.

Here is an example:

```
<PathFigure x:Name="pathFigure" StartPoint="{Binding Path=(Extensions:CustomExtensions.Radius), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource pointConverter}">
```

**Edit:**
I was unable to reproduce your issue.
I use following code and text-block has correct output:

```
<ProgressBar Extensions:CustomExtensions.Radius="80" Name="test"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=test, Path=(Extensions:CustomExtensions.Radius)}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong in my original answer, the type of the attached property was correctly defined and it should be `CustomExtensions` not `ProgressBar`

> *ownerType* - The owner type that is registering the dependency property.
>   [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597495.aspx)

<s>You have to set to ProgressBar your attached property `typeof(ProgressBar)`</s>

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Radius", typeof(string),
        typeof(CustomExtensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string))
    );
```

Here's how you could easily test

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="testProgressBar"
             Value="50"
             local:CustomExtensions.Radius="140 0" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=testProgressBar, Path=Radius}"/>
```